# Get the value of a field inside a paragraph field in hook_preprocess_field

Tags: 8

I'm usign the module Paragraphs for Drupal 8. I need to print the raw value of a paragraph field in the twig template, so I'm trying to access to the value of the field in the hook_preprocess_field, but I don't know how to access the value in $variables.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can use preprocess field hook which is supported in drupal 8 also . Example below:

```
function example_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    if (($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'example')) {
    //get the value of the field
    dsm($variables);
   print_r($variables);
    // add a class to the field        
    $variables['attributes']['class'] = [
     'example'
      ];
  }
}
```

Comment: dsm function needs devel module, so before running this code install that module.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. But I don't know why when I print the content of the array in the hook_preprocess_field, the value of that field is not present. Maybe because it is part of a paragraph field, I don't know. I could achieve what I needed using the variable paragraph instead of content in the twig template like in https://www.drupal.org/node/2662400 where it describes exactly the same scenario I have.

Comment: Yes, the values of paragraph fields are in the variable paragraph, but not in field.html.twig, but in paragraph.html.twig.

Answer (score 4):

To get at the value of a paragraphs field for manipulation etc you can use `template_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables)` or more specifically 
`template_preprocess_paragraph__PARAGRAPH_TYPE(&$variables)`

Answer (score 0):

One Good solution for that is to first install [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and then you can use dsm function.

this function is easy to use just write `dsm($variables)` and it will print a hierarchical form of element.

Using that you will know how to have access to your desired values and fields.